# Telerik UploadedFiles.SaveAs not overwrting

Tags: telerik

I have been trying to figure out why my telerik code has not worked. I am trying to overwrite a document that is currently stored at that specified path but it is not overwriting.

Here is the code

```
if(ulDocument.UploadedFiles.Count > 0){
    string targetFolder = Server.MapPath("~\Documents\PDF\");
    LogInfo(ulDocument.UploadedFiles[0].FileName);
    ulDocument.UploadedFiles[0].SaveAs(Path.Combine(targetFolder, String.Format("{0}{1}", shi.Id, ulDocument.UploadedFiles[0].GetExtension())), true);        
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception or it's just not working?  have you verified the file paths to save are correct?

Comment: No exceptions are being thrown. The paths are fine. I have even tried another path and it still doesn't override the file.